# GA4 e-commerce not tracking revenue./ prices

Tags: e-commerce, google-analytics-4

I'm having a strange issue where I've made triple sure that the GA4 e-commerce events, for example the purchase event, have all required fields set. I can see the items array with "price" properties, have the mandatory item_name and id_id, have a value property for the complete purchase but all the purchases tracked have a value of 0.
Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: Are you setting the value for the whole event/purchase? An example of what you are sending would help.

Comment: Yes, I'm sending both, an item price and a value for the transaction. I've added an example above, thanks!

Comment: I would debug through the stages. Does the debug view show the value? Is the value a number or a string?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have added currency parameter. Apparently GA4 doesn't recognize revenue if there is no "Currency" associated with it. If you are using GTM, make sure the tag has Currency under event parameters.